# Google places API's image response

Tags: regex, api

Hi need to get the image reference of a place with the google API, but the [Places's API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos?hl=fr)'s response is :

```
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"><TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY><H1>302 Moved</H1>The document has moved<A HREF="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipPp0PH6F8kZlrNa7yWAzY2sxjdCzmbMz_qPH12H=s1600-w400">here</A>.</BODY></HTML>
```

So i would like to find a way to get just the "href" content of the link ?

Comment: 1.- load it as HTML 2.- xpath to A to get the HREF attribute 3.- Get the content of URL with curl for example, the other way is add the "FOLLOW LOCATION" "true" to the request call.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=HREF=")(.*?)(?=">)
```

Should work.

- `(?<=HREF=")` is a positive lookbehind that starts at an
  occurrence of " HREF=" "
- `(.*?)` captures the string you want (the image reference)
- `(?=">)` is a positive lookahead that stops at an occurrence of " "> " (non-greedy because of the ? in `(.*?)`)